# Search Keyword Highlight In accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple accordion in single page and i am seraching the keword in the header of each accordion and want to highlight the search text but the following code is searching the keyword but not highlighting the text.

```
enter code here
var search = document.getElementById('searchAns'),
    accordions = document.querySelectorAll('.find-ans-card');
if (search) {
    // Apply search
    search.addEventListener('input', function () {
        var searchText = search.value.toLowerCase();
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(accordions, function (accordion) {
            if (accordion.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) >= 0) {
                accordion.style.display = 'block';
                //accordion.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText).style.bgColor = 'black';
                
            }
            else {
                accordion.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: please update a working example , so that people can refer and help u out

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, this is the same thing i wanted jut wanted to highlight the text which search in the search box https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55324783/live-search-for-accordions-and-its-content

Comment: this would help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript)

Comment: thank you for the help, but that is not working for me